# My C# function will not work

Tags: c#

I have made a function called "AddNumbers" but when I call it, I get an error that says "An object reference is needed". I have placed this function outside of the Main() entry point, but I am sure it has nothing to do with placement because I tried moving it and it would still not work.

```
namespace FunctionPractice
{
     class Program
     {
        public int AddNumbers(int number1, int number2)
        {
            int result = number1 + number2;
            return result;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 2 numbers: ");
            int firstNumber = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            int secondNumber = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            int result = AddNumbers(firstNumber, secondNumber);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Main` is `static` but `AddNumbers` is not.

Comment: You can also create an instance of Program class in main method and access the AddNumbers method. See my answer for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the method declaration to

```
 public static int AddNumbers(int number1, int number2)
```

Or create an instance of Program class in main method and then access the add numbers method.

```
 namespace FunctionPractice
 {
      class Program
      {
         public int AddNumbers(int number1, int number2)
         {
             int result = number1 + number2;
             return result;
         }

         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Enter 2 numbers: ");
             int firstNumber = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
             int secondNumber = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            Program program = new Program();

            int result = program.AddNumbers(firstNumber, secondNumber);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting way to solve the problem.

Comment: And also instead on Convert.ToInt16, try using Int16.TryParse. You can avoid throwing unnecessary exception by using TryParse.

Comment: what is the difference between the conversion and the Prase? What does the Parse do?

Comment: Parsing means **analyzing**. Convert.ToInt16 will throw exception if conversion fails. TryParse will never throw exception. Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Awesome, I will start using that. Good read, thanks

Comment: Mo Mehdi, **choose one answer as correct answer**. You'll gain more reputation by doing so and on stackoverflow reputation is directly linked to privileges.

Comment: No problem, I put yours as the good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Si `main` is `static`, `AddNumbers` must be static as well.

Comment: Yes! It worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hey your method works fine you just need to make your "AddNumbers" method static. You can't call a non-static method from a static one. Also you may want to add a read line to the end so the program doesn't just shut off once it writes to the screen. Here would be the fixed code.

```
class Program
{
    public static int AddNumbers(int number1, int number2)
    {
        int result = number1 + number2;
        return result;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 2 numbers: ");
        int firstNumber = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        int secondNumber = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

        int result = AddNumbers(firstNumber, secondNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, dude. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Make your function as
`public static int AddNumbers(int number1, int number2)`.

This is because, you are calling your function from a static function which belongs to the class itself. Your function belongs to the objects of the class. So when you call static function `main()`, it doesn't know of which instance's `AddNumbers` to call. Hence the error. Please read more about `static` keyword.